# CORS for AWS API Gateway return HTTP 500

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, curl, sails.js

I've a simple API Gateway, that sends the data to an HTTP endpoint (Express/Node).

For testing, I'm using curl, which is great. Sending the curl request without CORS works like a charm, however if I try to mimic CORS in curl, I get a HTTP 500 and have no idea why. These are both requests:

```
curl -v -H "X-Api-Key: myapikey" -H "Origin: example.com" "https://apigatewayid.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/path/prettyParam?anotherParam=1" 

*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to apigatewayid.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
* Server certificate: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> GET /dev/path/prettyParam?anotherParam=1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: apigatewayid.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> X-Api-Key: myapikey
> Origin: example.com
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 64
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Fri, 21 Jul 2017 00:28:50 GMT
< x-amzn-RequestId: numbers-6dab-11e7-b411-b7f8fd6c0cc3
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-5morenumbersletters3e8be5c86a2c72781a0b356
< X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 numbersletters7a8621aabe6b30d2f5a48.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: numberslettersUk3Bs9dL4KJR4QccPmILA4tJUjO0X_h7cQc9DxA==
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host apigatewayid.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com left intact
{"resultDataFromServer":"dataReceived!"}


curl -H "Origin: example.com" -H "X-Api-Key: myapikey" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET"  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" -X OPTIONS --verbose "https://apigatewayid.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/path/prettyParam?anotherParam=1" 


*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to apigatewayid.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
* Server certificate: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> OPTIONS /dev/path/prettyParam?anotherParam=1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: apigatewayid.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> X-Api-Key: myapikey
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With
> 
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 36
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Fri, 21 Jul 2017 00:29:07 GMT
< x-amzn-RequestId: numbers-6dab-11e7-b411-b7f8fd6c0cc3
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,OPTIONS
< X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 numbersletters7a8621aabe6b30d2f5a48.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: numberslettersUk3Bs9dL4KJR4QccPmILA4tJUjO0X_h7cQc9DxA==
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host apigatewayid.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com left intact
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I enabled CORS in the API Gateway, and in Express CORS is enabled also, so not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

@Raul, did you test your API method via API Gateway? Try deploying your API again and test it from the APIGateway itself by providing the URL param. If you get the same `{"message": "Internal server error"}` there is a problem with the code. Sometimes it might look like a CORS issue, but actually it could be a lambda logic error.